# Encrypt password was shows Chinese language

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change a password, in a stored procedure from NVARCHAR into its MD5 hash, but after executing it the password hash is shown as Chinese characters. Why?

I am using this code `EncryptByPassPhrase('MD5', @Password)` but it still shows the result as Chinese characters

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);
SELECT @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),@Password);


Insert Into tblUserLogin (ICNumber,Email,[Password],CreateBy,CreateDate,LastUpdateBy,LastUpdateDate)
Values (@ICNumber,@Email,HASHBYTES('SHA1',@HashThis),@FirstName,GETDATE(),@FirstName,GETDATE())

END
```

The Expected Result should like this:

> 0x01000000E6A0E10AF0144E38670D9B8E92E6E22787F9CD27B467E253

But the Actual Result is:

> 詫鸺쇬⒍맣㮶뎨뗮兴サ

Comment: The query doesn't correspond on what you said you are doing.

Comment: What is the type of parameter @Password and of that Password column? A hash is a byte array that you cannot treat as a string. Random bytes in an nvarchar column may well represent Chinese characters

Comment: Password is nvarchar...okay , what type's suitable for encrypted?

Comment: @AidilScaft, (1) see my answer, (2) you're not encrypting when you use `HASHBYTES`, you're generating a hash. Encryption is reversible, given the encryption key, hashing isn't =)

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're storing the result of calling the [`HASHBYTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function into an `NVARCHAR` field when you should store it in a `VARBINARY`.

Here's a worked example that shows this:

```
CREATE TABLE UserHash
(
    [Password_NVARCHAR] NVARCHAR(200),
    [Password_VARBINARY] VARBINARY(20)
)

DECLARE @Password NVARCHAR(20) = 'Abcdefghijklmnop'
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);
SELECT @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),@Password);

INSERT
INTO    [UserHash]
        (
            Password_NVARCHAR,
            Password_VARBINARY
        )
SELECT  HASHBYTES('SHA1',@HashThis),
        HASHBYTES('SHA1',@HashThis)

SELECT  *
FROM    [UserHash]
```

Here's the result of the last statement in that code:
[image: The results as shown in SQL Server Management Studio]

As you can see, the `NVARCHAR` version shows something you're not expecting which is because the result of calling `HASHBYTES` is being interpreted as text, rather than as a series of bytes.

If you look at the length of the text in the `Password_NVARCHAR` field (e.g. by executing `SELECT LEN(Password_NVARCHAR) FROM [UserHash]`) you'll see this returned as **10**. As [`NVARCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) stores text using 2 bytes per character, your 20 byte hash is being displayed as a 10 character string.

**NOTE**: In the script above I've sized `Password_VARBINARY` to fit an SHA1 result, as per the linked documentation for `HASHBYTES` you should size the column according to the hashing algorithm being used:

> The output conforms to the algorithm standard: 128 bits (16 bytes) for MD2, MD4, and MD5; 160 bits (20 bytes) for SHA and SHA1; 256 bits (32 bytes) for SHA2_256, and 512 bits (64 bytes) for SHA2_512

**ASIDE**: Don't store a password as a hash, use a [Salted Hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure-for-password-storage).